# Less compiling variable with other variable name error

Tags: javascript, css, compiler-construction, less

I have a problem with variables declared with other variable name.
In the below mixin I have a variable declared with other variable name like:

```
.label-color(@color) {
  @label-class:~"label-@{color}";
  @badge-class:~"badge-@{color}";
    @label-color:@@label-class;


 .@{label-class}, .@{badge-class} {
    background-color:@label-color !important;
 }  
}


.label-arrow(@color) {
   @label-class:~"label-@{color}";
   @label-color:@@label-class;

  .@{label-class}{
    &.arrowed:before {
        border-right-color:@label-color;
    }
    &.arrowed-in:before {
        border-color:@label-color;
    }
    &.arrowed-right:after {
        border-left-color:@label-color;
    }
    &.arrowed-in-right:after {
        border-color:@label-color;
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately my compiler does not recognize this kind of  `@label-color:@@label-class;` and pull out error at this line.
What modification should I do in order to compile well this part of my less.

ty.

Comment: If your compiler does not understand `@@` (btw., which one is it? I thought they all do) there's not much you can do except changing the compiler. Theoretically it is possible to rewrite anything w/o `@@` but we need to see all involved code (in particular how, where and more important why these `@label-[color]` variables are defined that way).

Comment: Btw., this is the same example as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24079918/2712740) one, where do you guys take this code from? (I can't be sure w/o seeing it all but it's definitely looks like a slightly overengineered snippet and most likely it can be simplified).

Comment: @ I have this less from a theme and crunch compile very well but unfortunately less4j is not compiling @@ :| and I have in my project less4j that compile automatically .

Comment: less4j? Hmm, I was sure it [does support](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Variables#as-reference) `@@`. What error message do you get and what less4j version it is?

Comment: @seven-phases-max I have 1.5.4 version. error: Caused by: com.github.sommeri.less4j.Less4jException: Could not compile less. 119 error(s) occurred:
ERROR file:/C:/Users/EclipseWorkspace/Project/target/classes/ro/btn/fault/themes/less/blueSilver/label-badge.less 50:16 Variable indirection works only with string values

Comment: OK, the error message is the answer, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lessj4 seems to support variable referencing only by *quoted string* values so you have to split concatenation and escaping there (i.e. do not use `~"..."` for `@@` variables). E.g. the first mixin would look like this then:

```
.label-color(@color) {
    @label-color_: "label-@{color}";
    @label-color: @@label-color_;

    .label-@{color}, .badge-@{color} {
        background-color: @label-color !important;
    }  
}
```

Same changes for the second mixin. (Assuming both mixins are invoked like `.label-color(~"red");` or like `.label-color(potato);`).

Comment: Are you sure this should work? If I remove ~ will raise the error variable @label-@{color} not declared :(

Comment: >Are you sure this should work? - No, I don't have less4j installed so I can only guess (using [the docs](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/_pages)). Ok, what does happen if you temporary replace `@{color}` with its actual value? Does it compile then?